# Install apps on iPhone from Windows programmatically

Tags: iphone, windows, installation, reverse-engineering

Is there an official API to communicate with iPhone from Windows programmatically?

There are [some apps](http://www.imobie.com/phonetrans) that do that, but they require iTunes to be installed.

I wonder how one can develop such an app.

Does one have to reverse engineer something?
I heard [Apple doesn't like 3rd party apps](http://www.pcworld.com/article/163909/article.html) and wants everybody to use iTunes (and therefore doesn't provide any API).

Is it illegal to develop such an app?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for the [TotalCommander file manager](http://ghisler.com/) called [t-pot](https://code.google.com/p/t-pot/) that allows browsing the contents of an iPod Touch or iPhone. Looking at its code hosted on google code could help.

Answer (score 1):

[libmobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) has an API for that.

```
instproxy_error_t instproxy_install (instproxy_client_t client, 
        const char * pkg_path, 
        plist_t client_options, 
        instproxy_status_cb_t status_cb, 
        void * user_data 
    )    

Install an application on the device.
```